# Expresses feeling of security or safety with positive inflections

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

First of all thanks to that great community here!

We are trying to find a word or phrase to represent 'strong secure feelings' in a 'content & elated' way - (network security and safety / open source / protection).

We want to convey a message like "**We protect the confidentiality, integrity and availability of information in the system**."

The words/names should have a 'strong emotional appeal' therefore. Words with Anglo-Saxon, Anglo-Norman roots are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Confidence

If a company has confidence in their product, they'll offer their customer, a money back guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.